# Can I create an instance by reflection and specify the overloaded "params" constructor when there is only one argument c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a type that has two constructors (ConstructorTestClass), one that has a single parameter of params TestClass[] and the other of TestClass. I have to invoke an instance of TestClass by reflection and then invoke an instance of ConstructorTestClass by reflection using the TestClass instance as the constructor argument.

I want to be able to create my instance of ConstructorTestClass using the params constructor.

Here is a code sample demonstrating my problem;

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(ConstructorTestClass).Assembly;

            var parameter = assembly.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass).FullName);

            var parameters = new object[] { parameter }; 

            var result = assembly.CreateInstance(typeof(ConstructorTestClass).FullName, false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, parameters, null, null);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class ConstructorTestClass
    {
        private readonly string _constructor;
        public string ConstructorSignature { get; }
        public ConstructorTestClass(params TestClass[] foo)
        {
            _constructor = "params TestClass[] foo";
        }

    public ConstructorTestClass(TestClass foo)
    {
        _constructor = "TestClass foo";
    }

    public override string ToString() => _constructor;
    }

    internal class TestClass { }
}
```

The second constructor (TestClass Foo) is always invoked. If I comment out this constructor the code continues to work but instead calls the other constructor.

I can also get the params constructor to be invoked if I cast the parameters to the correct type;

```
var parameters =  new object[] { new TestClass[] { parameter as TestClass } };
```

This does not solve the problem however because I would not know the type in the real code in which I need this feature.

I have also tried getting the specific constructor I need and invoking it directly;

```
var constructor = typeof(DummyConstructorTestClass).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TestClass[]) });
var result = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { new object[] { parameter } });
```

Unfortunately this also fails because of the type mismatch (object[] is not TestClass[])

Can I invoke the params constructor by reflection in this case?

Comment: Well the last line it should work if you use `constructor.Invoke(new object[]{new TestClass[]{parameter as TestClass}});`  did you try to use `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass), 1)` to create the params array? (Here you could replace `typeof(TestClass)` with a `Type` instance you probably have at runtime.

Comment: To understand the real problem it could be helpful if you provide a [mcve] that shows which (type) information you actually _do_ have when trying to find the constructor

Comment: @Rene I did not try that, but I certainly will now. Thanks

Comment: The information on the type I do have is its full name, the constructorInfo.ToString() of the constructor that I need to call and the full name of the types that should be supplied. I also have an instance of the assembly to which everything belongs.

Comment: Do you know (at compile time) that the constructor takes an array of the parameter type or do you need to infer this information from the `constructorInfo.ToString()`, too?

Comment: Not at compile time, I can get an instance of the ConstructorInfo and get information about its parameters from there.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm a little confused now: if you don't know anything about the constructor at compile time, how do you know you want the second one? ...oh you accepted, seems it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given information you can create your instance like that:

```
private static object CallConstructor(Assembly asm, string constructorTestClassName, string testClassName)
{
    Type paramType = asm.GetType(testClassName);
    var paramsArray = Array.CreateInstance(paramType, 1);
    paramsArray.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(paramType), 0);
    var parameters = new object[] {paramsArray};

    return asm.CreateInstance(constructorTestClassName, true, 
                  BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, 
                  parameters, null, null);
}
```